# Reliability and Performance Monitor Data Collector Set : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: windows-vista, performance-monitoring

When I try to start a Data Collector Set in the Reliability and Performance Monitor in Windows Vista Business I receive the following error:

> When attempting to start the Data
>   Collector Set the following system
>   error occured:
>
> Logon failure: unknown user name or
>   bad password.

What could be causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "General" tab for the set properties there's a "Run as" buttonm that you can use to set what account it runs as. Try running as the local Administrator and confirm that works, then try using a less privileged account as appropriate.

JR

Comment: My account is a local admin, and I also tried the vista Run As Administrator command and it still didn't work

Comment: Data collector sets don't necessarily run as the user who is running Perfmon. That's because they have to run even when the PC is logged out. That's why there's an option to set the account in the set properties. Try setting the set properties to use the administrator account.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realise you meant set as in Collector Set - I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Have you got user access control turned on? If so that my be interfering. When UAC is on members of the local Administrators group (apart from Administrator itself) don't get full Administrator rights.

Comment: UAC is turned on. When I run the Monitor as Admin, and go to the Set properties, the button to change the user that the set runs as is disabled, and the box saying which user is empty.

Comment: I ended up creating new User Data Collector set based on the Performance one